# Python - Abort 2 threads from getting access to array at same time

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading

I want to do something like this and I dont know how :

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
def main():
    # disable arr access to other threads; they will have to wait if they need to read
    while len(arr) != 0: 
    item = arr[i]
    arr.remove(item)
    #enable access to other threads
    print item 

thread1.run(main) 
thread2.run(main)
```

that the result of this will be - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 
and no double printing of a variable

Comment: You need to use locks: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects

Comment: Offtopic: ou can remove an element by its index by using `arr.pop` instead of `arr.remove` which will perform better in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from threading impor Lock

arr_lock = Lock()
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
def main():
    # Disable arr access to other threads; they will have to wait if they need to read
    arr_lock.acquire()
    # Do whatever you want
    item = arr.pop(i)  # What is i?
    # Enable access to other threads
    arr_lock.release()

    print item 

thread1.run(main) 
thread2.run(main)
```

Comment: LOVE U <3333333